# Selenium: Select dates from a calendar

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to automate checking hotel prices via the website [www.trivago.ie](http://www.trivago.ie)
I am struggling to select the dates from the calendar which pops up after you select a hotel.

I can't seem to get the correct class to allow me to select and update both the start and end date. I have attached my basic code below. Could someone please help me extend it such that I can select the dates after I have selected the hotel.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('window-size=2560,1440')
chrome_options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome('*/drivers/chromedriver/win32/91.0.4472.101/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

# Open the website page
driver.get('https://www.trivago.ie')

# Enter the hotel into the search box
driver.find_element_by_id("querytext").send_keys("test hotel")

# Allow time for options to populate
time.sleep(1)

# Select the first suggestion
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ssg-suggestion__info")[0].click()

# Allow time for the calander to pop-up
time.sleep(3)

# Try, but fail, to select the date
#driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cal-day cal-is-weekend cal-is-selectable")[0].click()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("cal-heading-month cal-heading-day4").click()
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I have hit quite the road-block.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 There is "Accept cookies" button. You have to click it, otherwise you will not be able to click dates correctly.

2 You need to wait till the first date is clickable and click it afterwards.

3 `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains` - Import ActionChains for selecting a second date. Selenium will move to it and click the date.

4 Make sure the locators you are using are unique. Check the ones from my solution.

Note that I used `time.sleep(3)` to wait for cookies OK button. `element_to_be_clickable` did not work because the button is moving. Here is the field for improvements.

**SOLUTION**

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('window-size=2560,1440')
chrome_options = Options()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', chrome_options=options)

# Open the website page
driver.get('https://www.trivago.ie')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Accept cookies
time.sleep(3)
accept_cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#onetrust-button-group>#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept_cookies)

# Enter the hotel into the search box
driver.find_element_by_id("querytext").send_keys("test hotel")

# Allow time for options to populate
time.sleep(1)

# Select the first suggestion
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ssg-suggestion__info")[0].click()


# Allow the time for the first date to become clickable and click it

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "time[datetime='2021-07-01']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("time[datetime='2021-07-11']").click()

#  Move to the next date and click it
second_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("time[datetime='2021-07-15']")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(second_date)
actions.click().perform()
```

Result (selected dates):

[image]

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to select the first available date (and default to a one day stay), there is a class for the first available date. So the following is working for me:

```
# Try, but fail, to select the date
#driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cal-day cal-is-weekend cal-is-selectable")[0].click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name("cal-is-range-start").click()
time.sleep(1)#time for end date to populate
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.search-button__label').click()
```

Comment: 1 second sleep may be not enough

Comment: Agreed.I was going with the given approach and tinkering as little as possible, but I prefer what you do in using waits rather than sleeps.